# How to add Facebook Share button in Android Application

Tags: android, facebook

I am beginner in android.I want to add FacebookShare button in my android application.I create the app in 2.2 .please help me
I use this code

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getResources().getStri‌​ng(R.string.title_activity_android_face_book_share));
emailIntent.putExtra(android‌​.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_android_face_book_share));  
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

I Use the following link also [Best way for social sharing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656641/best-way-for-social-sharing-in-android)

Comment: See both of this links. Its very good Example to learn for beginners . - http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/290-facebook-integration-in-your-android-application - http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/

Comment: You will need to give more details in your post fella. Just asking for what you need is not how SO works. Show us what you have done and then ask questions when you are stuck with your code.

Comment: Uhhh. Not in a comment. Edit your post and add the code there.

Comment: @user1597094: Before being sarcastic or even rude for that matter, you might consider reading the FAQ's on how to ask a good question. Calling my second comment a _replay_ shows you in bad light. Not me mate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
  shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "URLyouWantToShare");
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
```

Use the ACTION_SEND Intent, add the URL you want to share. User will be given a selection of apps to accept the share intent such as facebook etc.

Comment: It shows the dialog box and installed app in my device .whether i installed facebook app the action is performed during the app.but the device is not having the facebook app ? how to share a contents to facebook

Comment: Im unaware of any url type method to share data to facebook that could be simply opened in a browser, with this method you will only see choices that share an Intent for ACTION_SEND

Comment: can you do a picture with a message together?

Comment: Can someone give me any info on how to add the original Facebook Share Button on my app ? By original i mean blue background, rounded, white font color etc. Thanks in advance!!